# Hazelcast and Apache Ignite analog for Redis Scored Sorted set

Tags: redis, hazelcast, ignite

I have used Redis' [Sorted sets](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets) to build fast leaderboard solutions for games.
There are two main query operations I needed for my task:

1. Get elements and their scores from index A to B in descending order ([ZREVRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) in Redis)
2. Get an index and a score of a particular element in descending order ([ZREVRANK](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrank) in Redis)

As I know Redis uses special data structure for Sorted Set, which combines some kind of skip list with hash table.

Now I want to migrate from Redis to modern IMDG solutions and choosing between Hazelcast and Apache Ignite. What are the closest analogs of Redis Sorted Sets and ZREVRANGE, ZREVRANK operations in Hazelcast/Apache Ignite?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a really complex task to implement a leaderboard in a distributed system like IMDG. Correct me if I'm wrong but ZSET is a more a local thing in `Redis`, you can't have a Sorted Set bigger than your biggest shard.
I'd like to split the issue into two separate cases: local and distributed.

- Local. In general in `Ignite` it could be achieved by making a cache [REPLICATED](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#replicated-mode). It would be possible to use local `SQL` queries with `LIMIT/OFFSET` but as far as I know there's no fast (`O(log(n)`) index jump to start further scanning from some row with a particular number. It makes it impossible to achieve overall complexity of `O(log(n) + m)` where `m` is a window size. Theoretically it's possible to implement that. I've initiated the [discussion](http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Limit-Offset-index-scan-td49070.html) on the "Apache Ignite Developers" list. Anyway it all depends on your real use-case: how many users you have, what's the target latency, percentiles etc.
- Distributed. Here it becomes much more complex as there's no guarantee that in case of a [PARTITIONED](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#partitioned-mode) cache it is enough to get values from every node with ranks from `a` to `b` because data [distribution](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#affinity-function) (affinity maps a key to a node) can be not absolutely even. It means that you need to scan the entire index on every node until you reach `b` (or closest value above).

Comment: For my use case distributed version of Scored Set is not needed actually. Sharding could be done not inside the concrete data structure, but among data structures of the same type. E.g. I could have many Sorted Sets each of which as a whole should be spread in the cluster,not distinct elements.

Still I need log(n) complexity badly without the need of mapreduce etc, since there could be millions of items in the set (still within one node) and the operation is done frequently by many users.

If Redis is the only in memory db system which supports such feature, it seems I should not swap.

Answer (score 0):

In Hazelcast you can create `IndexType.SORTED`. Please check the related documentation, [Hazelcast Reference Manual: Indexing Queries](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#indexing-queries).

Comment: Rafal, thank you for your reply. The docs are pretty well, but I haven't found what I need, since both operations (ZREVRANGE and ZREVRANK) work on indices (e.g. row number in sorted table) rather than sort field value. I haven't found such direct possibility in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's possible to leverage [query entities](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#query-configuration-using-queryentity) in `Apache Ignite`.
Here's a raw example.

```xml
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <property name="name" value="testCache"/>
    <property name="queryEntities">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                <property name="keyType" value="com.company.ScoreAndId"/>

                <property name="keyFields">
                    <list>
                        <value>score</value>
                        <value>id</value>
                    </list>
                </property>

                <property name="valueType" value="com.company.UserInfo"/>

                <property name="fields">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="score" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                        <entry key="id" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                        <entry key="name" value="java.lang.String"/>
                    </map>
                </property>

                <property name="indexes">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                            <constructor-arg value="id"/>
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <list>
                                    <value>score</value>
                                    <value>id</value>
                                </list>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg value="SORTED"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After that it will be possible to use regular `SQL` queries to obtain data from a cache. Table name is going to be `"USERINFO"` as it's inherited from the type name: `UserInfo`, anyway it's possible to [reconfigure](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/QueryEntity.html#setTableName-java.lang.String-) that. A schema comes from a cache name.
For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM "testCache"."USERINFO" WHERE SCORE > ? AND SCORE < ?;
```

It will make a range index scan.
You can run an `EXPLAIN` command to check what index is being used (in the example we have 2 of them).

```
explain SELECT * FROM "testCache"."USERINFO" WHERE SCORE > ? AND SCORE < ?;
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thx for the answer. In your example you are selecting from score to score, but redis allows to select from index to index (for example from 100-150 place in leaderbord)